# C# Cannot implicitely convert type "X" to string[][]

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a list that I'm trying to convert to a jagged array (string) and I'm getting:

> cannot implicitly convert type to string{}{}

I have this class structure:

```
internal class ProcessedZip
{
    public string ErrorFound {get; set;}
    public string IsEnabled {get, set;}
    //6 others...
}
```

I have a function that processes ZipFiles (public string[][]  (params)

I create a variable:
var processedZips = new List();

I have a loop and within the loop I do:

```
processedZips.Add(new ProcessedZip
{
    ErrorFound = errorFound.ToString();
    IsEnabled = isEnabled.ToString();
    //the other 6....
}
```

When the loop finishes, I want to return a jagged string array. I cannot seem to figure out how to convert my list to a jagged array. I've tried:

```
return processedZips.ToArray();
return processZips.Select(i=> new ProcessedZip()).ToArray();
return processedZips.Select(i = new[] {i}).ToArray();
```

They all return:

> Cannot implicitly convert BOA.Models.ProcessedZip[] to string[][]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to specify how your `ProcessedZip` class is converted into a `string[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess: you want to convert a single `ProcessedZip` to a `string[]` by adding all 6 string properties:

```
string[][] result = processedZips
    .Select(p => new[]{ p.ErrorFound, p.IsEnabled, ... })
    .ToArray();
```

A jagged array like `string[][]` is an array whose elements are arrays, in this case string-arrays. So the LINQ query selects arrays and with `ToArray` they're added to a `string[][]`.

Comment: Thank you Tim, makes perfect sense to me now. Appreciate the quick answer....that worked.